# Python: checking type of variables

Tags: python, isinstance

I have a question about python.

I have variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

And I have the following line:

```
if    not isinstance(a, int)   or not isinstance(b, int)  \
   or not isinstance(c, int)   or not isinstance(d, int)  \
   or not isinstance(a, float) or not isinstance(b, float)\
   or not isinstance(c, float) or not isinstance(d, float):
    do something
```

Is it possible to make this code shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: Since either `isinstance(a, int)` or `isinstance(a, float)` is going to be False, the smartass answer is that the if is always true and can be omitted entirely...

Comment: I would just omit the checking and catch any resulting errors in the following code.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, please, to see the problem....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U should use `all`:

```
if not all(isinstance(var, (int, float)) for var in [a, b, c, d]):
    # do stuff
```

Note, that you can supply both `int` and 'float' to the `isinstance` call.

Comment: Use generator expression. Otherwise all element are tested.

Comment: It should be `not all(...)` or `any(not ...)`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1.0
>>> c = 123
>>> d = 233
>>> any((type(var) in (int, float) for var in [a,b,c,d]))
True
>>> c = 'hello'
>>> any((type(var) in (int, float) for var in [a,b,c,d]))
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = b = c = d = []
>>> any(not isinstance(x, (int, float)) for x in [a,b,c,d])
True
>>> d = 0
>>> any(not isinstance(x, (int, float)) for x in [a,b,c,d])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you've write is equal to

```
if True:
    do_somthing
    pass
```

Comment: You should have developped your answer

Answer (score -3):

Clearly, you didn't take enough attention to the  RemcoGerlich's comment, since you upvoted and accepted a senseless answer.
At the time I write this, 4 other people upvoted the same senseless answer.
That's incredible.
Will you see better with this ? :

```
def OP(a,b,c):
    return    not isinstance(a, int)\
           or not isinstance(b, int)\
           or not isinstance(c, int)\
           or not isinstance(a, float)\
           or not isinstance(b, float)\
           or not isinstance(c, float)

def AZ(a,b,c):
    return all(isinstance(var, (int, float))
               for var in [a, b, c])

gen = ((a,b,c) for a in (1, 1.1 ,'a')
       for b in (2, 2.2, 'b') for c in (3, 3.3, 'c'))

print '                  OPv | AZv     OPv is AZv\n'\
      '                 -----|-----    -----------'
OPV_list = []
for a,b,c in gen:
    OPv = OP(a,b,c)
    OPV_list.append(OPv)
    AZv = AZ(a,b,c)
    print '%3r  %3r  %3r    %s | %s      %s'\
          % (a,b,c,OPv,AZv,OPv is AZv if OPv is not AZv else '')

print '-------------    ----'
print 'all(OPV_list) : ',all(OPV_list)
```

result
OPv = yours
AZv = senseless answer
I limited to a,b,c to make it short

```
                  OPv | AZv     OPv is AZv
                 -----|-----    -----------
  1    2    3    True | True      
  1    2  3.3    True | True      
  1    2  'c'    True | False      False
  1  2.2    3    True | True      
  1  2.2  3.3    True | True      
  1  2.2  'c'    True | False      False
  1  'b'    3    True | False      False
  1  'b'  3.3    True | False      False
  1  'b'  'c'    True | False      False
1.1    2    3    True | True      
1.1    2  3.3    True | True      
1.1    2  'c'    True | False      False
1.1  2.2    3    True | True      
1.1  2.2  3.3    True | True      
1.1  2.2  'c'    True | False      False
1.1  'b'    3    True | False      False
1.1  'b'  3.3    True | False      False
1.1  'b'  'c'    True | False      False
'a'    2    3    True | False      False
'a'    2  3.3    True | False      False
'a'    2  'c'    True | False      False
'a'  2.2    3    True | False      False
'a'  2.2  3.3    True | False      False
'a'  2.2  'c'    True | False      False
'a'  'b'    3    True | False      False
'a'  'b'  3.3    True | False      False
'a'  'b'  'c'    True | False      False
-------------    ----
all(OPV_list) :  True
```