# check if varible is either of type string or int

Tags: python, types

I am trying to check whether variable data is either of type string or integer so that i can work on it.If its none of the above it is supposed to return false. I have tried to use `isinstance` but it requires data to be of both types which is impossible. Any better method of doing it?
Here is my code:

```
     if isinstance(data(int, str)):
         return True
     else:
         return false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is an integer or a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488278/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: checking type of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704455/python-checking-type-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact,you can use a tuple of classes as 2nd argument to `isinstance`.

```
isinstance(var,(list,int))
```

**isinstance(object, classinfo)**

> If classinfo is a tuple of class or type objects (or recursively,
>   other such tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the
>   classes or types. If classinfo is not a class, type, or tuple of
>   classes, types, and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.

Comment: @Nix. Check out your code.`isinstance(data(int, str))` you missed a comma.And `isinstance` method absolutely can do this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use boolean `or` :

```
>>> isinstance(3,int) or isinstance(3,str)
True
>>> isinstance("3",int) or isinstance("3",str)
True
>>> isinstance([3],int) or isinstance([3],str)
False
```

or specify a tuple of possible types :

```
>>> isinstance(3, (int, str))
True
>>> isinstance("3", (int, str))
True
>>> isinstance([3], (int, str))
False
```

So in your case, it wouldn't be :

```
isinstance(data(int, str))
```

but

```
isinstance(data, (int, str))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **isinstance(object, classinfo)** built-in function.

[This](https://repl.it/Fw63/1) should do the job

```
def isStrOrInt(myVar):
  return isinstance(myVar,int) or isinstance(myVar,str)


print(isStrOrInt(5))   # True
print(isStrOrInt('5')) # True
print(isStrOrInt([]))  # False
print(isStrOrInt('Dinosaurs are Awesome!')) # True
print(isStrOrInt(3.141592653589793238462 )) # False (Because it's a decimal not an int)
```

Here's the running version: https://repl.it/Fw63/1

---

This is what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) says:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo
>   argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If
>   object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns
>   false. If classinfo is a tuple of type objects (or recursively, other
>   such tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the
>   types. If classinfo is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a
>   TypeError exception is raised.

*Basically, `isinstance` takes 2 parameters, the first is the variable you want to check, and the second is the data type/ class you want to check if it is an instance of (in your case `int` or `str`). [This tutorial](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-given-class-or-of-a-subclass-of-it.htm) explains it well.*

Comment: Thanks alot. With your explanation it means my code was almost right. Whats was missing was justa comma after data `isinstance(data, (int, str))` like @Eric has explained. I really appreciate